# To pass something one does not want onto someone without them really wanting it

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

I am looking for a word that means to give something to someone without them really having a need for it or wanting it. To give away something one doesn't want to someone else who doesn't want it either, however, they accept it out of kindness. To burden someone with something, so to speak.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try ***foist***
Defined by [Macmillan](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/us/dictionary/american/foist) as:

> (foist something on/upon someone) **to force someone to accept or deal with something that they do not want**

For example:

> I don’t want to have to take home the last piece of cake so I will see if I can foist it on Sally.

Or:

> Jim didn’t want to take home the last piece of cake so he foisted it onto me- like I need another piece of cake.

Answer (score 1):

**saddle** (v.)

> transitive. To put (a burden) on or upon a person, group, etc.; to
> impose (something) as a burden or responsibility. OED

> load or burden; encumber
> *He saddled me with that heavy
> responsibility* [vocabulary.com](https://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/saddle)

---

> **Giving Kitchen Tools As Gifts**
> Don't
>
> Or, at least not without talking to the luck recipient. It's virtually
> impossible to predict someone else's needs and tastes in kitchen
> tools, and for all the reasons just discussed, **saddling** them with
> the wrong tool might be worse than giving them nothing at all. [Jeff
> Potter; *Cooking for Geeks*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Cooking_for_Geeks/IQ3PJY7zs6EC?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=saddling%20them%20with%20gifts&pg=PA78&printsec=frontcover).

> In recommending ministers for possible posts in other jurisdictions,
> they follow a high standard of frankness since none wants to be
> **saddled** with a problem cleric nor be blamed by another executive for simply unloading a problem. [W. E. Wiest; *Ethics in Ministry*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Ethics_in_Ministry/2UPOLp9mkhEC?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22Saddled%20with%20a%20problem%22&pg=PA44&printsec=frontcover)

> Don't **saddle** someone with a secret. If you do, expect them to tell
> someone. [Faye Snyder; *The Manual*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/The_Manual/epPRAwAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22don%27t%20saddle%20someone%20with%22&pg=PA378&printsec=frontcover)

> The worst of it was that she had not **saddled** herself with that encumberance.  She would have been so content with a mere sisterly responsibility,
> such as she had assumed to the policeman in Heath Drive, but this
> fairy godmother who had first knocked down her companion and then
> picked him up, had **saddled** her with this greater embarrassment,
> and she had been stupid enough to acquiesce. [M. Bryant; *Mrs.
> Fuller*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Mrs_Fuller/IeJOAQAAMAAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22Saddled%20her%20with%22&pg=PA59&printsec=frontcover)

Answer (score 1):

**Fob off**

> transitive verb
>
> 1: to put off with a trick, excuse, or inferior substitute
> 2: to pass or offer (something spurious) as genuine
> 3: to put aside

“Fob off.” Merriam-Webster.com Dictionary, Merriam-Webster, https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/fob%20off. Accessed 17 Sep. 2021.

The examples given in MW give a better idea of modern usage -

"people who try to fob off to charities broken-down furniture that is fit only for the junkyard."

"now fob off what once they would have welcomed eagerly"
— Walter Lippmann